# Regular Expressions How to append matches from raw string text into a list

Tags: python, regex

Hello I have some messy text I am unable to process in any good way and I want to match all zip codes 5 digit numbers from the raw string then append them to a list.  My string looks something like this:

```
string = '''
         January 2020
          Zip Code                                                                                            
           Current Month
        Sales Breakdown
      (by type)
              Last Month                Last Year     Year-to-Date
         95608
         Carmichael
         95610
        Citrus Heights
        95621
        Citrus Heights
         95624
         Elk Grove
         95626
         Elverta
         95628
         Fair Oaks
          95630
           Folsom
          95632
         Galt
        95638
        Herald
        95641
         Isleton
         95655
        Mather
       95660
        North Highlands
        95662
        Orangevale
            Total Sales                                                                                         
         43               REO Sales 0                                                      45                
        40                             43
           Median Sales Price                                                             $417,000             
                  $0                                      $410,000                 $400,000     
        $417,000
        '''
```

Comment: `zips = re.findall(r'\b\d{5}\b', string)`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Ups, excuse me @Nick, I didn't see your comment before to post my answer.

Comment: @Ivanhercaz that's no problem; I could have answered but didn't because I expect this question will get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I am totally agree too :(

Answer (score -1):

It can be done with `re.findall` and the regular expression `\b\d{5}\b` or even just `\d{5}`. Let's see an example:

```
import re

string = '''
         January 2020
          Zip Code                                                                                            
           Current Month
        Sales Breakdown
      (by type)
              Last Month                Last Year     Year-to-Date
         95608
         Carmichael
         95610
        Citrus Heights
        95621
        Citrus Heights
         95624
         Elk Grove
         95626
         Elverta
         95628
         Fair Oaks
          95630
           Folsom
          95632
         Galt
        95638
        Herald
        95641
         Isleton
         95655
        Mather
       95660
        North Highlands
        95662
        Orangevale
            Total Sales                                                                                         
         43               REO Sales 0                                                      45                
        40                             43
           Median Sales Price                                                             $417,000             
                  $0                                      $410,000                 $400,000     
        $417,000
        '''

regex = r'\b\d{5}\b'

zip_codes = re.findall(regex, string)
```

Then you can get each code from `zip_codes`. I recommend you to read [re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) and [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/regex.html). There are interesting tools to write and test regex, as [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

I also recommend you that for the next time you ask, please investigate a bit by yourself and then try to do what you want, and then, if you have an issue, ask for this specific issue. The help page [How I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimum, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help you to write a good question.

Comment: If the negative vote is due to some error in my answer I would be very grateful to know it and learn! Thanks in advance.